# Change Linkedin Company Profile plugin Width

Tags: javascript, css, linkedin-api

I have been trying to figure out how to change the size of the Linkedin Company Profile width which we can create [here](https://developer.linkedin.com/plugins/company-profile-plugin). They will give you two script tag which will create the widget for you in your site. Nothing else. So you have no control over your css.

I had been struggling for days and finally figured it out. I tried to add inline styling on the site even with the `!important` tag but it still took the styles from the `linkedin.css`. I tried styling it every possible way but didn't work.

Since SO allows to share knowledge as Q&A format I thought of sharing this. Please see the answer below.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here's an example of how to provide the width to a plugin:

```
<script src="http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="IN/MemberProfile" data-id="http://www.linkedin.com/in/xxx" data-format="inline" data-width="400"></script>
```

You can add a `data-width="400"` attribute to the script tag. That's all.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, excellent! FYI, the badge seems to have a minimum width of around 300px. I tried placing it inside a wordpress sidebar of 260px and it chops off the side of it. Would you have any clue as to solving this issue?

Comment: @HenrikSöderlund  As far as I've been able to gather, linkedIn doesn't seem to care much for letting developers be able to customize their plugin (at least the company profile one).  It's frustrating, especially when trying to make a responsive website.  It seems there's a min-width set of 300px so even if you set `data-width="100%"` the smallest it will resize is 300px.
Check this forum post/comment thread [http://developer.linkedin.com/forum/define-height-width-embedded-company-profile]