# how to change Linkedin Widget background color to transparent?

Tags: plugins, widget, linkedin-api

I'm trying to customize Linkedin's Company Insider Plugin and there aren't many options or documentation around to change background color to transparent.

As far as I've seen this plugin has two iframes nested. The white background color is inside the second one in a `<div class="wrapper">`.

There are some options available for the Profile plugin like `data-width` or `data-format` as this answer describes:
[Change Linkedin Company Profile plugin Width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14868355/change-linkedin-company-profile-plugin-width)

Any clues about the background color?

Before any answer about jQuery like this won't work:

`$("#iframe").contents().find(".wrapper").css('background-color', 'transparent');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LinkedIn's widget does not provide any official support for this level of customization at this time.